# Conditional probability - inequality (sums of i.i.d random variables)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality

Any help in starting this would be appreciated.

Let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ where $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are iid random variables, and let $x,x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that

$$\mathbb{P}(S_n \geqslant x | X_1 \leqslant x_1, \dots, X_n \leqslant x_n) \leqslant \mathbb{P}(S_n \geqslant x)$$

I am also given that for any r.v $Y$ and non - decreasing function $f$ such that $f(X+Y)$ integrable then $$\mathbb{E}[f(X+Y)|X\leqslant x)] \leqslant  \mathbb{E}[f(X+Y)] $$